# ActiveAdmin - Custom action to create a new record (missing required keys: :id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a custom action that allows to create a new record (in addition to the default new and create actions).

I simply added a new member action and a link via `action_item`. The link generation already fails with `No route matches {:action=>"new_photo_order", :controller=>"admin/orders"} missing required keys: [:id]`.

```
action_item :new_photo_order, only: :index do
  link_to 'New photo order', new_photo_order_admin_order_path
end

member_action :new_photo_order, method: [:get, :post] do
  if request.post?
    # create resource
  else
    # render template with form
  end
end
```

I couldn't find any solutions so I'm asking how are you supposed to add a custom action that allows to add a new record?

Comment: Could you post the related route in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: It's activeadmin so routes are generated automatically. Nothing added in routes.rb file. The routes that the member_action is creating:

`new_photo_order_admin_order GET    /admin/orders/:id/new_photo_order(.:format)                      admin/orders#new_photo_order`
                              `POST   /admin/orders/:id/new_photo_order(.:format)                      admin/orders#new_photo_order`

Comment: @schneikai have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
member_action :new_photo_order, method: [:get, :post] do
  if request.post?
    # create resource
  else
    # render template with form
  end
end
```

to this

```
collection_action :new_photo_order, method: [:get, :post] do
      if request.post?
        # create resource
      else
        # render template with form
      end
    end
```

because when we define a `member_action` it defines a route like `orders/:id/new_photo_order` which expects `id`. or if you want to use `member_action`, you need to pass the order Id in your action_item like this

```
action_item :new_photo_order, only: :index do
  link_to 'New photo order', new_photo_order_admin_order_path(order.id)
end
```

Comment: Hey Talha, thanks for your answer. I was aware of `collection_action` but because it's actually supposed to work on collections (obvious :) I tried to do it with `member_action` because it felt more correct.

Comment: To use it with `member_action` you should move the `action_item` to `show` or `edit` of order, in this way you will have the order_id and can pass it to `link_to` helper.

Comment: Yeah, but for a new order there is no id.